# SimpledateFormat returning different value for different Android version

Tags: android, timezone, simpledateformat

I've used the `SimpleDateFormat` in my code as given below.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ZZZZ");
```

I want to display the result as `GMT-05:00`. I'm running my code in Android 4.3. It returned the same result as I expected. However, the above line of code returned `-05:00` instead of `GMT-05:00` for Android version 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2 (`GMT` is missing). I'm confused. I already read the Android's [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Can anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the documentation only shows the latest version, I couldn't find whether `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ZZZZ");` always return `GMT-05:00` before Android 4.3.

The best approximation that I can think is `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT'Z", Locale.US);` where it will add GMT explicitly, but the time format is without colon (e.g. `GMT-0500`).

---

Edit: if you can assure that on 4.1 and 4.2, your code returns `-05:00`, then I think you can add version checker and decide which `SimpleDateFormat` will be used.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ZZZZ", Locale.US);
} else {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT'ZZZZ", Locale.US);
}
```

Comment: Hi @antimo, I'm using the same logic now in my code. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. This is very strange. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormats` to convert Dates to Strings in any timezone:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out also:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy");
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but with 'ZZZZZ', I found that some SimpleDateFormat fixes were added only on 4.3+ : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73209

Since 'ZZZZZ' and 'ZZZZ' were documented together,I am assuming the behaviour is as expected in 4.0, 4.1 & 4.2